# Le mot « empathie » n'est pas dans le dictionnaire ?

Tags: vocabulaire, orthographe

Avec surprise je n'ai pas trouvé le mot *empathie* [au CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/empathie) ? J'ai contrôlé et recontrôlé mon orthographe… il ne me semble pas avoir fait d'erreur ? Ce mot n'est-il donc pas français ? Ou pas suffisamment utilisé ? (Mais tout le monde l'utilise il me semble) Qu'est-il alors ?

Comment: It's just missing from the TLFi. You can find it anywhere else.

Comment: Il est possible que le CNRTL n'est pas référencé le mot dans leur base de données.

Comment: C'est quand même fou qu'une démarche qui me parait assez scientifique oublie des mots ?? Et ça me gène beaucoup puisque le TLFI est... mon seul dictionnaire :-) (à part les wikis, évidemment). Il va falloir que je m'achète un dico papier, alors... la galère...

Comment: Je suis totalement époustouflé par cette découverte... un mythe s'effondre.

Comment: @Istao Existe-t-il dans le dico papier s'il n'existe pas sur la version Internet?

Answer (score 1):

D'après le dictionnaire historique de la langue française, il s'agit d'un terme du XXème siècle qui vient de l'anglais *empathy* qui est lui-même une traduction de l'allemand *Einfühlung* (mot utilisé par T. Lipps qui a inventé le concept en psychologie).